# C# Installer passing data to installer class

Tags: c#, installation

I have a setup project for a windows service.  I am trying to pass information from the setup exe to the installer class in the windows service project.  As an example, I've set the Arguments in the install custom actions to the following:

```
/targetdir="[TARGETDIR]"
```

In the Install method of the installer class, I'm looking for all the keys in the Context.Parameters:

```
string keys = "";
foreach (string key in Context.Parameters.Keys) keys += key + "|";
```

targetdir does not show up.  How do I pass the information to my installer?

Thanks!

**Edit 1:**  Found that I can get custom textbox information to the install class using the CustomActionData, but, if I try to add TARGETDIR there, it throws an exception.  I can get the info using assemblypath, but is there a way to pass TARGETDIR in?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to attack this. There is a good discussion on this subject here: http://www.theserverside.net/discussions/thread.tss?thread_id=23903#155056

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hmm.  This appears to discuss more of the running of the service rather than the install process.  I'm really looking to get the information from the setup UI to the installer class.